# What is differentiable real-valued functions?

Tags: linear-algebra

This is one example from the book $Linear\, Algebra\, Done\, Right $ that I cannot understand well:

"The set of differentiable real-valued functions $f$ on the interval (0, 3) such that $f'(2)=b$ is a subspace of $\mathbf{R}^{(0,3)}$ if and only if $b=0$."

For example, $f(x)=x$, I thought $f'(2)=1 \neq 0$, and $f(x)$ is a differentiable real-valued function right? Where am I wrong? Thanks.

Comment: You are just saying that the set can be non-empty even when $b \neq 0$. That doesn't make the  set a subspace.

Comment: The subspace consists of differentiable real valued functions which satisfies $f'(2)=0$. The function $g(x)=x$ is not in this subspace.

Comment: It is only a sub*space* if $f'(2)=0$. You can construct any sub*set* you like.

Comment: Oh right! Thanks. Could I ask what does the $f(x)$ looks like?